# How to extract data from the following using RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

I have a data set in the following pattern

```
1<a href="/contact/">Joe</a><br />joe.doe@somemail.com</div>
2<a href="/contact/">Tom</a><br />tom.cat@aol.com</div>
3<a href="/contact/">Jerry</a><br />jerry.mouse@yahoo.co.in</div>
```

So on...

I need to extract the name and email id alone from it. How do I do it?

---

### Update:

Based on your responses, I've changed my data format to:

```
1(name)Joe(email)joe.doe@somemail.com(end)
2(name)Tom(email)tom.cat@aol.com(end)
3(name)Jerry(email)jerry.mouse@yahoo.co.in(end)
```

How do I parse *that*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\(name\)(.*)\(email\)(.*)\(end\)
```

Now, the first backreference `\1` contains the name, and the second backreference `\2` contains the email address.

Keep calling the same regex to get the next name and email address.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Use an HTML parser. There are a bunch listed on [this page](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers). Based on my experience using [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), I would suggest [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). From their page:

> JTidy is a Java port of HTML Tidy, a HTML syntax checker and pretty printer. Like its non-Java cousin, JTidy can be used as a **tool for cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML**. In addition, JTidy provides a DOM interface to the document that is being processed, **which effectively makes you able to use JTidy as a DOM parser for real-world HTML.**

**UPDATE**

Based on the edit to your question, use [`split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the string with `\([a-z]+\)` as a delimiter. This should give you the separate components:

```
String[] components = str.split("\\([a-z]+\\)");
```

Or you could use the more generic expression `\(.*?\)`.

Comment: This is no more a well formed HTML document.

Comment: @Ragunath. If it's not a well-formed document, you can still run it through Tidy to tidy it up, and then parse it.

Comment: Ok what would you do if the above dataset looked like **1(abc)Joe(def)joe.doe@somemail.com(xyz)** forget HTML for a while.

Comment: You could tokenize it using `\\([a-z]+\\)` as a separator (for that exact example that you have provided).

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that this will be the standard pattern for all of your entries, you can simply use String.split() on each line, using the regular expression (.*?) as the split pattern. This will match the ( followed by the *least possible number* of other characters, followed by another ). So the code looks something like this:

```
//for each String line
String[] items = line.split("\\(.*?\\)");
name = items[0];
email = items[1];
```